# How do you check if a picturebox is touching a picturebox that is in a certain array?

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of pictureboxes named `slimeList`. I have it so that the pictureboxes in `slimeList` move around the screen. I have a timer on the Form, an on each tick, I want to check for each element of `slimeList` if it is touching another element of `slimeList.` The code snippet below shows how the pictureboxes of `slimelist` are moving around:

```
For Each obj In slimeList
            If DistanceBtwn(obj.Location, MouseFollower.Location) > 2 Then
                Randomize()
                Glide(obj, MouseFollower.Location, CInt(Math.Floor(4 * Rnd())) + 1)
            End If
Next obj
```

As you can see here, the pictureboxes in `slimeList` are following something called the `MouseFollower`.
I want to make another for loop like this:

```
For Each obj In slimeList
            If obj [is touching a picturebox which is in slimeList] Then
                [expression]
            End If
Next obj
```

Comment: Side note: You only need to call `Randomize()` **once** in your application; the `Load()` event is a good place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox` class defines the `Bounds` property with is a `System.Drawing.Rectangle`.  `Rectangle`s can figure out if they are touching another rectangle with the .`IntersectsWith` method.

```
'  Check that the list is not nothing and contains more than 1 element before continuing.
  For outerIndex As Int32 = 0 To slimeList.Count - 2
      For innerIndex As Int32 = outerIndex + 1 To slimeList.Count - 1
          If slimeList(outerIndex).Bounds.IntersectsWith( slimeList(innerIndex).Bounds ) Then
              ' slimeList(outerIndex) and slimeList(innerIndex) have collided.
          End If
      Next
  Next
```